# How to make use of two buttons with two different actions in the same form?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, django-forms

I have a form that has two buttons/input.

Button1 saves the page and refresh it.

Button2 saves the page and goes to another url.

Button1 is working with **type="submit"** and then view.py takes the data, saves them and refresh the data.

My problem is with Button2. I added it with *formaction="{% url 'team_area:home' %}"* and actually redirect me but the problem is that it doesn't save the data. Button1 still works properly.

Is it possible to have some sort of request.the_id_of_pressed_button to use in view.py?

---

If it can be helpful here are my files involved:

modify_players.html

```
<h1>AREA SQUADRA</h1>
<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <h2>Giocatori</h2>
  {{ player_formset.management_form }}
  {% for player_form in player_formset %}
    {% if forloop.last %}
      {% if not forloop.first %}
        <input type="submit" value="Salva" formaction="{% url 'team_area:home' %}">
      {% endif %}
      <h5>Nuovo giocatore:</h5>
    {% endif %}
    {% for field in player_form %}
      {% if forloop.revcounter == 2 %}
        {{ field }}
      {% elif forloop.parentloop.last and forloop.last%}
      {% else %}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
      <br>
  {% endfor %}
  <input type="submit" value="Aggiungi">
  </form>
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def modify_players(request):
    if request.user.team is not None:
        PlayerFormSet = modelformset_factory(Player, form=PlayerForm, extra=1, can_delete=True,)

        if request.method == "POST":
            player_formset = PlayerFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=Player.objects.all().filter(team=request.user.team),)
            for player_form in player_formset:
                if player_form.is_valid():
                    player = player_form.save(commit=False)
                    player.team = request.user.team
            if player_formset.is_valid():
                player_formset.save()

            return redirect('team_area:modify_players')
        else:
            player_formset = PlayerFormSet(queryset=Player.objects.all().filter(team=request.user.team))
        return render(request, 'team_area/modify_players.html', {'player_formset': player_formset})
    else:
        return redirect('team_area:home')
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need two submit buttons? I ask because there might be another, better solution than adding two buttons.

Comment: @xyres I need that when I press them both save the data but the first one take me to a page, the second to another page

Comment: The fact is similar to how admin Django app modifies models. There are the buttons 'Save' and 'Save and continue editing'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comments cleared up a couple of things.

Remove `formaction` from the `input` so that both the buttons submit the form to the same view.

Give both the buttons a common `name` but different `value`. Then in your view, you can differentiate which button was clicked.

html:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="button1">
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="button2">
```

view:

```
def modify_players(...):
    ...
    # save data
    ...

    submit_button = request.POST.get('submit_button')
    if submit_button == 'button1':
        # refresh page
    else:
        # redirect to some page
```

Comment: Just what I was searching for! I would ask you this: if I don't set a name for <input> how is it passed trough request.POST? Can I use the get()?

Comment: @LorenzoFiamingo Without a `name` attribute, the value of input isn't sent to the backend. Although, form will be submitted if it is `type="submit"`.